# React webapp - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build my react application, using Visual Studio Code, by tyiping

```
yarn run build
```

But the error that I get is the following

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders 

| 
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <App />,
|   document.getElementById('root')
| );
```

As requested in the answer, here follows the code of my package.json (I removed some of the dependencies otherwise there was too much code for stack overflow in the question)

```
{
    "name": "react-portfolio",
    "homepage": "https://StonesCutter.github.io/react-portfolio",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
         ...
        "yarn": "^1.22.19"
         ...
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "predeploy": "yarn run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
    }
}
```

Do you know how could I fix this problem?

Comment: `yarn run build` can be anything. Show your `package.json`

Comment: I edited with part of the package.json as you suggested

Comment: Change `build` script to `"react-scripts build"`

Comment: You need to share your webpack config. It appears that your webpack config does not contain a loader for jsx files, eg babel-loader.

Comment: Also: if you’re started your project using CRA or some kind of framework (NextJS for example), this configuration should already be handled for you automatically in their boilerplates. Have you considered doing so? Manually setting up webpack to build a react app is totally doable but just very cumbersome, and requires extensive knowledge on how Babel works (and what packages, presets and plugins you need).